Is there any possibility to create a Non Transferable TOKEN_2022 with Metadata Data in it?
I am trying to build a token that I could airdrop to an account, and not be able to be transferred between accounts.
I had two ideas:
TOKEN_2022 Unfreeze Account -> Mint -> Freeze Account
TOKEN_2022 Non Transferable Mint with Metadata
Now when trying to create a Mint account TOKEN_2022_Program in the same instruction with the Non Transferable Mint and createCreateMetadataAccountV3Instruction I get the following error:
'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s invoke [1]'
'Program log: Instruction not supported for ProgrammableNonFungible assets'
This is the code for it:
import {
  getExplorerLink,
  getKeypairFromEnvironment,
} from "@solana-developers/helpers";
import {
  clusterApiUrl,
  Connection,
  Keypair,
  PublicKey,
  sendAndConfirmTransaction,
  Transaction,
} from "@solana/web3.js";
import web3 from "@solana/web3.js";
import {
  TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
  TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
  MINT_SIZE,
  getMinimumBalanceForRentExemptMint,
  createInitializeNonTransferableMintInstruction,
  createInitializeMintInstruction,
  getMintLen,
  ExtensionType,
} from "@solana/spl-token";
import { createCreateMetadataAccountV3Instruction } from "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata";

const TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID = new web3.PublicKey(
  "metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s"
);

//Freeze the authority
export async function initMint() {
  const {
    connection,
    keyPair,
    mintKeypair,
    mintPK,
    freezeAuthority,
    uri,
    mintLen,
    decimals,
    programId,
    lamports,
  } = await getConnHelpers();

  //Metadata account
  const metadataPdaAndBump = web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    [
      Buffer.from("metadata"),
      TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID.toBuffer(),
      mintPK.toBuffer(),
    ],
    TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID
  );

  const metadataData = {
    name: "name",
    symbol: "name",
    uri: uri,
    sellerFeeBasisPoints: 0,
    creators: null,
    collection: null,
    uses: null,
  };

  const metadataPda = metadataPdaAndBump[0];

  const createMetadataAccountInstruction =
    createCreateMetadataAccountV3Instruction(
      {
        metadata: metadataPda,
        mint: mintPK,
        mintAuthority: keyPair.publicKey,
        payer: keyPair.publicKey,
        updateAuthority: keyPair.publicKey,
      },
      {
        createMetadataAccountArgsV3: {
          collectionDetails: null,
          data: metadataData,
          isMutable: false,
        },
      }
    );

  //Non transferrable token mint extension
  const initializeNonTransferableMintInstruction =
    createInitializeNonTransferableMintInstruction(mintPK, programId);

  const createMintInstruction = [
    web3.SystemProgram.createAccount({
      fromPubkey: keyPair.publicKey,
      newAccountPubkey: mintPK,
      space: mintLen,
      lamports,
      programId,
    }),
    createInitializeNonTransferableMintInstruction(
      mintKeypair.publicKey,
      programId
    ),
    createInitializeMintInstruction(
      mintKeypair.publicKey,
      decimals,
      keyPair.publicKey,
      null,
      programId
    ),
  ];

  const tx = new Transaction();
  tx.add(...createMintInstruction);
  tx.add(createMetadataAccountInstruction);

  const signature = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, tx, [
    keyPair,
    mintKeypair,
  ]);

  const link = getExplorerLink("transaction", signature, "devnet");
  console.log(link);
}

async function getConnHelpers() {
  const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"));

  const keyPair = getKeypairFromEnvironment("SECRET_KEY");
  const mintKeypair = Keypair.generate();
  const mintPK = mintKeypair.publicKey;
  const freezeAuthority = mintKeypair.publicKey;

  const uri = "jsonurl";

  const mintLen = getMintLen([ExtensionType.NonTransferable]);
  const decimals = 2;
  const programId = TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID;
  const lamports = await connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(mintLen);

  return {
    connection,
    keyPair,
    mintKeypair,
    mintPK,
    freezeAuthority,
    uri,
    mintLen,
    decimals,
    programId,
    lamports,
  };
}

If you have any other idea to have a token with metadata, with the possibility to be minted and not transferrable between token accounts, please leave idea.
